# What's different between hinge loss and squared hinge loss in SVC?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, loss-functions

As the title says, What's different between hinge loss and squared hinge loss in SVC and how they effect on the decision boundary? And could you tell me when hinge loss is better than squared hinge and Vice versa?